# Universal Links in iOS 9.2.1 - Single domain and signing

Tags: ios9, applinks, ios-universal-links

Unfortunately I can't get Universal Links to work in iOS 9.2.1.

Everything verifies correctly in the Apple Verification Tool and the Apple SearchBot, however links simply don't open.

There are two things that are slightly different with my setup:

1. I only have a https://www.domain.com, https://domain.com does not work.
   I therefore have only created one listing in the Entitlements file,

   ```
   <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains </key>
   <array>
       <string>applinks:www.domain.com</string>
   </array>
   ```
2. I haven't signed the apple-app-site-association file as I've read this isn't required on the iOS 9+ release.

Here's my app association file:

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "...",
                "paths": [ "*", "/", "/X/*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to sign the AASA file, although it's fine if you do. When you say 'simply do not open', do you mean they do not correctly open your app? A lot of 3rd party apps and Browsers break Universal Links, which is unfortunate, so try clicking your link from from Notes or iMessage initially (instead of manually entering into Safari). A comprehensive list of behaviors for ULs can be found here(provided by Branch Metrics):
https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/#appsbrowsers-that-support-universal-links

Additionally, please note that Universal Linking has to be cross-domain - ie, you can't link within the same domain. This is just an inherent limitation of Universal Links.

Answer (score 0):

Check apple-app-site-association path. According to documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW4 you can put it in
`https://<domain>/apple-app-site-association`
or
`https://<domain>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`
But 2nd url works with ios 9.3 and later. For 9.2.1 you should upload apple-app-site-association file to the root.